# Post install after installing package?

Tags: node.js

I've got a scripts tag in my package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "<command>"
  }
```

Whenever I'm running `npm install` the postinstall commands runs properly.
But if i'm passing arguments to the `npm install` command, for example when installing a new package: `npm install <dependency> --save-dev`. it won't run the `postinstall` command.

is there a way that the postinstall will run even if there are arguments in the `npm install` command?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused about how packages actually work. A package has it's own dependencies, post-installs and pre-installs. When you install a package like this:

`npm install <dependency>`

This looks at the package you want to install and installs it along with it's dependencies, if the package you want to install has a `preinstall` or `postinstall` command, it invokes them. But **only for that package**, not yours.

When you do `npm install`, this is installing **your** package, and it therefore calls **your** package's `postinstall` command.